# Highcharts : axis with multiple colour

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show 2 colours on the axis for values from -1 to 1

[single colour](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotlines-color/)

[is this useful for my case.](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/coloraxis/multiple-coloraxis/)

[image: i wnat to plot like this]

```
    xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],

    plotLines: [{
        color: '#FF0000',
        width: 2,
        value: 5.5
    }]
},
```

```
    colorAxis: [{
    minColor: '#000fb0',
    maxColor: '#e3e5ff',
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return Math.abs(this.value) + '%';
        }
    }
}, {
    minColor: '#ffece8',
    maxColor: '#8a1900',
    labels: {
        format: "{value}%"
    }
}],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the lines by using `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class. Example:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            render: function() {
                var yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
                    x = this.plotLeft,
                    y1 = this.plotTop,
                    y2 = yAxis.toPixels(150),
                    y3 = y1 + this.plotHeight,
                    path1 = ['M', x, y1, 'L', x, y2],
                    path2 = ['M', x, y2, 'L', x, y3];

                if (!this.customLines) {
                    this.customLines = [];

                    this.customLines.push(
                        this.renderer.path(path1)
                        .attr({
                            'stroke-width': 4,
                            stroke: 'green'
                        })
                        .add()
                    );

                    this.customLines.push(
                        this.renderer.path(path2)
                        .attr({
                            'stroke-width': 4,
                            stroke: 'red'
                        })
                        .add()
                    );

                } else {
                    this.customLines[0].attr({
                        d: path1
                    });
                    this.customLines[1].attr({
                        d: path2
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9p4ku13e/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path